# adjusting one column in a R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and I want to adjust one columb down 2 rows (

current dataframe:

```
old <- data.frame(names=c("alice", "everett", "emil", 
"jonas", "peter", "jacob"),
           score=c(23,24,25,26,32,33),
           atribute=c(543,567,543,457,657,876))
```

Desired dataframe:

```
    new <- data.frame(names=c("alice", "everett", "emil", 
     "jonas", "peter", "jacob"),
                score=c(23,24,25,26,32,33),
                atribute=c(0,0, 543,567,543,457))
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this? (currently, I sepeate out names as key, then I am making a new column with rbind and then merging... but there must be an easier way?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `base R`, we can concatenate 2 0s at the top while removing the last 2 elements from the 'atribute'

```
old$atribute <- c(0, 0, head(old$atribute,-2))
old$atribute
#[1]   0   0 543 567 543 457
```

Or to make it more efficient, we can just use indexing with `c`

```
nr <- nrow(old)
c(0, 0, old$atribute[-c(nr-1, nr)])
#[1]   0   0 543 567 543 457
```

---

In `data.table`, we can use `shift`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(old)[, atribute := shift(atribute, n = 2, fill = 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

to shift values use `lag`

```
library(tidyverse)
old %>% 
  mutate(atribute = lag(atribute, 2, default = 0))
```